# My sound card does not capture stereo audio

Tags: debian, microphone

I have a **Sound Blaster** card:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: S3 [Sound Blaster Play! 3], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

It's usb, it has a headphone and microphone input. I have plugged in a stereo microphone but when doing a recording test:

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000 test.wav
```

The result is mono (not stereo) audio. It seems to only detect one of the microphones on both channels, the other one doesn't work. The microphone is fine, I have tested it in Windows and both channels work. I don't understand what could be happening and what I could do.

Comment: Typical microphone inputs are mono (and Line In are typically stereo). It isn't clear what test you actually performed in Windows, how was it connected and to which hardware.

Comment: I just tried it and you're right, in Windows it is heard in mono. I don't understand how I tried it last time to detect the stereo, I suppose it would be the microphone that the laptop had built in and I got confused at first.

So this particular card has a mono mic input? How could I be sure? Thank you very much mate.

Comment: Check the manufacturer's specifications. A stereo mic input would be a USP (unique selling point) therefore expect it to be front and center. If not then it's just a traditional mono one.

Comment: Stereo mics with dedicated single cable are rare [they had a bit of a try in the 70s but didn't catch on because they demand an entire dedicated circuit]. So much so that in pro audio, they are even cabled as two mono mics. The 'stereo' comes simply from the mic placement - coincident, M/S etc.